# app engine: upload file without form / without pre-generated upload url (from mobile app)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, file-upload, google-cloud-datastore, blob

I'm making an android app that uploads photos to an app engine backend.

According to the app engine [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html), the way to upload files is to present the user with a form that posts to a dynamic url that was generated before the form was rendered (e.g. http://mysite.com/_ah/upload/ag5kZXZ-aGVsbG93b3JsZHIbCxIVX19CbG9iVXBsb2FkU2Vzc2lvbl9fGB0M)

However, I want to upload photos straight from an android app, so I don't want to make request first to generate such an upload url.

Hence my question: How can I upload files to app engine using a static url (say /upload) with one request? I'm using the python version, and java code would also be cool!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You control the app - why not have it make a request for a URL to post to?

Comment: Thanks Nick, That's what I ended up doing, but in my mind 1 request is better than 2, especially they are coming from a mobile phone where the network might not always be good...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the new experimental [file-like API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore) to directly write data to the blobstore;
you just have to create your server component, Java servlet or Python web handler, that reads the multipart form and stores the image in the blobstore.

Comment: Did you find anything on the request object for reading a multipart form?